# How can I insert three bytes at the beginning of a Perl string?

Tags: perl, sockets

I am writing a Perl program that sends and receives messages from two sockets and acts as a switch. I have to modify the received messages received from one socket, prepend 3 bytes to the data, and finally send the modified messages to another socket. I adopt select()...sysread()...syswrite() mechanism to poll for messages between sockets. The received messages are stored in $buffer during modification.

Now I can use following way to get the received messages:

```
my $hexmsg = unpack("H*", $buffer);
my @msg = ( $hexmsg =~ m/../g );
```

then I can insert 3 bytes to @msg. However, I don't know how to pack the message in @msg into a scalar(such as $buffer) and send it to another socket by syswrite(). Can anybody help me? Thank you in advance!

BTW, are messages in $buffer binary?

Comment: Besides, I have tried 
my $shexmsg=join("",@msg);
$buffer=pack("X",$shexmsg);
where "X" denotes template of pack, such as "n*", "b*","u*". However, all failed... I don't know what to do...

Comment: Why not `$buffer = 'extra bytes' . $buffer;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, messages in $buffer are binary (if I'm guessing what you mean by that correctly).  If your only reason for unpacking it into @msg is to insert the bytes, don't.  Use [substr](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) instead, and just write out the changed $buffer.  For instance:

```
substr( $buffer, 0, 0, "\x01\x02\x03" ); # insert 3 bytes at beginning.
```

If you are doing other things with @msg, you could continue to use that as well as
doing the substr insert before writing it out, or you could use substr or pack or split
or vec or a regex to parse out the pieces you need.  You'd need to describe what you
are doing to get more specific help.

Comment: Besides inserting 3 bytes to $buffer, I also need to identify the header and body of the message.What should I do? Can substr() still work?

Comment: Finally I use @msg to analyze messages and insert 3 bytes into $buffer for specific messages.I think using substr($buffer,<start>,<offset>) can get specific info of message for analysis(for example msg type is denoted by 1 byte), but I didn't try this way.

Comment: By the way, if I also want to modify the first two bytes of $buffer,what should I do? Because the first two bytes of $buffer denotes the length of the message,and after inserting 3 bytes to the message, the message length also should be changed accordingly.

Comment: **Please** Don't start with one question, and then add more different questions after the first question was answered; ask *new* questions instead! Or maybe even better: Show the problem and asking all questions at once, but keep in mind that SO is *not* a "we write your code" platform.

Answer (score 1):

If you've used `unpack` to get the data from `$buffer`, have you tried using [`pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) to put the data back in there?

Comment: This has the benefit of using almost the exact same code both ways, as far as I remember. I could be wrong, though - pack() and unpack() are my current weak-points in Perl.

Comment: I tried 
my $shexmsg=join("",@msg);
$buffer=pack("X",$shexmsg);
where "X" denotes template of pack, such as "n*", "b*","u*". However, all failed... I don't know what to do...